# Google Maps KML Super-Overlay Doesn't Display High Detail Zoom Layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, gdal

I have a KML with high detail imagery organized into [super-overlays](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_21tutorial#superoverlays) (created using [gdal2tiles.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html)) that I'm trying to show in Google Maps.

This KML works fine and looks great in Google Earth but when it loads in Google Maps it doesn't load the more detailed image layers when a user zooms in.  Here's a screenshot illustration (and a [link to the full resolution version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsu72.jpg)):

[image: Google Earth vs. Google Maps KML Detail]

Here's the simple code I'm using to display the KML on Google Maps (you can also tinker with a live version on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vXWU6/6/)):

```js
function initialize() {
    var i = 1;
    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://towatchlist.com/files/MASTERL2_1393600_01_20130329_1753_1806_V01/doc.kml');
    kmzLayer.setMap(map);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

To see the KML in Google Earth as it should be displayed, go to the Add menu and Choose 'Network Link' and add [this url](http://towatchlist.com/files/MASTERL2_1393600_01_20130329_1753_1806_V01/doc.kml) to the link field.  Alternatively, you can download the KMZ version of the same file [here](http://towatchlist.com/files/MASTERL2_1393600_01_20130329_1753_1806_V01.kmz).

This seems like a bug in Google Maps, but does anyone know a good workaround or if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I also [posted a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6589) with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a [suggestion from a Google employee](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6589#c2) I changed some settings on gdal2tiles.py to make it generate HTML code for the overlay that works better.  I added two flags: `-w google` and `-g <apikey>` and used the HTML output of that to create the map and overlay.